# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error Raspberry pi B+ model + Adafruit LCD + Keypad

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm using Raspberry pi B+ model and Adafruit 16x2 character LCD plus keypad for raspberry pi https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage 
I made all the steps in the guidelines when I write the final step sudo python cahr_lcd_plat.py the terminal gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "char_lcd_plate.py", line 9, in lcd = LCD.Adafruit_charLCDPlate() File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 432, in init File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 150, in init File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 46, in init File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 130, in write_iodir File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 95, in writelist IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

anyone can help me please? I2C operates on smbus[1]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the device is not connected to the I2C bus.

I suggest you re-check your wiring and retry the script once `i2cdetect -y 1` shows the device on the bus.